# Simple auto-typer with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I want to make a small application that will type the number 1, wait an interval, type the number 2, wait an interval, type number 3, wait an interval, etc.

This works for typing one number over and over:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 18
    end tell
    return 2
end idle
```

But I'm struggling to get more than number to work:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 18
    end tell
    return 2
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 19
    end tell
    return 2
end idle
```

This doesn't work. Nor does this:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 18
        return 2
        key code 19
        return 2
    end tell
end idle
```

I don't know what else to try. Thank you!

Comment: I think my problem might be with `return`, is there a better way to delay within a handler?

Comment: Related tip: you can use `keystroke "1"` instead of `key code`. Keystroke lets you type in any text and have it typed for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `delay 2` instead of `return 2` — `return` exits from the loop!